# linux, read/write the same file from different process, the read process got some unexpected data

Tags: c, linux, fwrite, fread

The scenario:

1. process(A) opens file with `r+` mode.
2. process(B) opens the same file with `r+` mode.
3. process(A) writes some data into it, and `fflush()`.
4. process(A) notifies process(B) to read the data.
5. process(B) reads the data. <---- here is the problem.

**Got some unexpected bytes( 0000 0000 ...) at the head part, and the left bytes are correct**.

PS: The data size is about 16k, and I write/read it with one `fwrite()`/`fread()` call.

I also did a test, that is, if process(B) calls `fflush()` before reading the data, the result is correct.

My question is,

1. What is the correct way to make sure process(B) always be able to
   get the updated data?
2. As process(A) has called `fflush()` already, why process(B) also needs
   to fflush() before reading the data?

Comment: All file handling functions read and write *buffered*. If some part of the file is already in the buffers, it will not be read again from disk, but returned from the buffers instead - If you write to the same file from another process, the buffers will only be updated after a fflush() of that FILE. You may want to google for *file locking* mechanisms.

Comment: Post your code.  You'll get actual answers that way instead of guesses.

Answer (score 3):

Each *stream* must be flushed to insure the stream is ready for I/O. When you open your stream in process(A), you will use something similar to:

```
FILE *fpA = fopen (filename, "r+");
```

and then in process(B) you do something similar:

```
FILE *fpB = fopen (filename, "r+");
```

Both `fpA` and `fpB` are separate data streams for `filename`. Flusing only process(A)'s stream has no effect on what is in process(B)'s stream and vice versa. So the correct way is to insure each stream is flushed and ready for additional I/O.

Comment: Not really. This might help *a bit*, but imagine **both** processes are flushing at the very same (milli-/micro-)second. Without a specific locking mechanism, there is always a small slot of uncertainty where parts of the file are already written, parts are not, and the reading process reads a half-updated file.

Comment: thank you all, I think David is right, and also, I need a lock mechanism.